# class or attribute for positioning, which is better?

Tags: html, css, selector

There are several `input`s on a page, I want to select them with jQuery, there are two ways I can do: one is to add a class `XXX` to these `input`s, and use `$("input.XXX")`, the other is to add an attribute `XXX` and use `$("input[XXX]")`.

I prefer the later one, I don't like to mix class only for positioning with other style css, if someday someone wants to change style, S/he may delete all classes and add a new class(so my positioning class is gone).

But my friends say `class` selector is fater than `attribute`, and has a higer compatibility.

So am I wrong?

Comment: better to follow convention. for exam. for jq selector use class line this .js_myClass & for css .cs_myClass

Comment: This should have been tagged with jquery. When using classes, you must use attributes (`class` attributes), so it is unclear what you are asking. Moreover, “to add an attribute `XXX`” is vague—what attributes are you talking about? And like most “which is better” questions, this is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

Faster? Maybe. More compatible? Arguably - the presence or exact value of an attribute has always been selectable, but things like `^=`, `$=` etc. are more recent.

Ultimately, if there is a difference in speed, it will be practically zero.

`class` is best for a class of element. However, if your *only* aim is to select then with JavaScript/jQuery, it may be better to use a custom attribute. For instance, I like to use things like:

```
<textarea data-resizable></textarea>
```

Then I select `[data-resizable]` and add some resizing controls that are actually useful on mobile devices, as well as auto-resizing to fit content. A `class` would probably be inappropriate here.